# Some Properties of trace of linear maps.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, trace

I need help have to prove some properties of trace

Let S and T be linear maps on an Euclidean space V,

1. Show that $$\operatorname {trace} (ST)=\operatorname {trace} (TS)$$
2. Prove or disprove that $$\operatorname {trace} (ST)=\operatorname {trace} (T)\cdot\operatorname {trace} (S)$$
3. If for all linear map K $\operatorname {trace} (TK)= 0$ then show that, $T=0$

I was able to solve the first question using the fact that 
 for given matrices A and B we have,

$$(AB)_{i,j} = \sum_{k}a_{ik}b_{kj}$$

> Hence $$\operatorname {trace} (AB)= \sum_{i}(AB)_{i,i} = \sum_{i}\sum_{k}a_{ik}b_{ki}=\sum_{k}\sum_{i}b_{ki}a_{ik}  = \sum_{i}(BA)_{i,i}=\operatorname {trace} (AB) $$
>   is this correct? can anyone help with questions 2 and 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. All good.
2. What about $S=T=\operatorname{Id}$? Or any random matrices provided you are not cursed with bad luck.
3. **Hint:** what is $\operatorname{Tr}(MM^T)$ for a given matrix $M$?

Comment: Using your third hint, if $T^*$ is the adjoint of $T$, $\text{Tr } T^*T = 0$. This means all the eigenvalues of $T^*T$ and thus, of $\sqrt{T^*T}$ are zero. By singular value decomposition, $T= S\sqrt{T^*T}$ for some isometry $S$. As $\sqrt{T^*T} = 0$, $T = 0$.

I don't know where you were leading to with your hint, but there must be a better way to do it without using SVD etc.

Comment: @Anu The answer to my question in 3. is that $\operatorname{Tr}(MM^T)$ is the sum of the squares of all entries in $M$. Since the OP asks for the Euclidean case, it means we are over $\mathbb{R}$, therefore such a sum can be zero only if all entries are (ie $M=0$). There is no SVD here, just take $K=T^T$ in the question.

Comment: Thank you! I thought of the adjoint because of your hint, but I hadn't realized before that $\text{Tr } (MM^T)$ was the sum of squares of all entries in $M$. Over a complex field, I suppose using the conjugate transpose instead would yield the same result. 
That's a nice proof, thanks!

Comment: @Anu Thanks :) no worries.